# Why do my Linkedin permissions for /me not work

Tags: linkedin-api

I created a LinkedIn app to check out the capabilities of the API with the permissions stated below. However Whenever I make a basic request to the /me endpoint I get the following result:

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}
```

**Code**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Accept: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer {$accessBearerToken}"),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Any idea as to why, the permissions should suffice right?

- r_organization_social
- r_1st_connections_size
- r_ads_reporting
- r_emailaddress
- rw_organization_admin
- r_liteprofile
- r_basicprofile
- r_ads
- rw_ads
- w_member_social
- w_organization_social

#linkedin